# Disable or delete right click menus VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Whenever I right click on an excel sheet two menus come up: one with cut, copy, paste, etc. and one with font size, bold, italic etc.

I can customize the first one to have whatever command I want. The problem I have is that I want to DISABLE or DELETE the second one (the one with font size, bold, italic etc.)

I tried going through the entire CommandBars collection but couldnt find the one that I need to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open your registry editor.
2. If you are running Word 2007, navigate to:

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\Toolbars\Excel
3. If you are running Word 2010, navigate to:

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Toolbars\Excel
4. Right-click in a blank area in the right-hand panel and choose New and Click DWORD (32-bit) Value.
5. Name it AllowMenuFloaties.
6. Leave the Data value at 0×00000000 (0). In other words, don’t do a thing with it.
7. Return to Word and discover that that pesky Mini Toolbar is gone.

Note: If you don’t see any of these folders in your Windows Registry, try disabling the Mini Toolbar through the File > Options > General menu first. This makes the entry pop-up by adding a new registry key in it. Or, you can simply add the folder yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a REG file that covers Office 2013, 2010 and 2007 with Word, Excel and
Outlook:

```clj
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Toolbars\Word]
"AllowMenuFloaties"=dword:0
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Toolbars\Outlook]
"AllowMenuFloaties"=dword:0
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Toolbars\Excel]
"AllowMenuFloaties"=dword:0
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Toolbars\Word]
"AllowMenuFloaties"=dword:0
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Toolbars\Outlook]
"AllowMenuFloaties"=dword:0
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Toolbars\Excel]
"AllowMenuFloaties"=dword:0
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\Toolbars\Word]
"AllowMenuFloaties"=dword:0
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\Toolbars\Outlook]
"AllowMenuFloaties"=dword:0
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\Toolbars\Excel]
"AllowMenuFloaties"=dword:0
```